# alternative to bcmwl-kernel-source package

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

I am looking for a good and stable alternative to the bcmwl-kernel-source package in linux.  I've been using a very unreliable and basically crappy ndiswrapper setup, and it's not working for me anymore.  My wireless card needs a good 802.11n driver, one that lets me use it to its full capacity.  Currently bcmwl-kernel-source crashes my operating system beyond repair, i've had to reinstall multiple times trying to get it working.  I've also tried bcmwl-kernel-source on multiple distros, each producing the same result.  The card works beautifully under Windows, high FPS, and almost 100% connectivity.

My Card is and Asus PCE-AC66 PCI-E Wifi Adapter.  Can use 802.11A, B, G, and N.

Comment: Perhaps mentioning some details about your wireless card would make sense, no?

Comment: You know what, i'm really sorry, i thought i did, the edit must not have gone through, ill do that now...   Thanks!!

Comment: @holgero updated the question, thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer packages on Dell 1520, since bcmwl-kernel-source kills both WiFI and Ethernet. It works in latest Ubuntu and Kubuntu 13.10.

Not sure if "b43" is your case, but you can check if some packages maches your case:

```
apt-cache search firmware-
```